# How can I change the transparency of a turtle drawing

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying to change the transparency of my `turtle.cirlce()` in python. I have looked around the internet and can't find anything on it that works. I tried the 'RGBA' but it gave me an error as it only took 3 arguments in the RGB tuple.

TLDR: How can I change transparency of turtle drawings?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot change the transparency of turtle drawings.  You can mix the background and pen color to fake transparency, but it would still draw over any other drawings with a solid color.

Comment: Is there another way I can draw in python where I can use transparency?

Comment: You can try Pillow and the [ImageDraw](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html) module.  It supports transparency, and is much faster than turtle as well.